# Creating a max function from scratch (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, max

So I'm trying to create a function that determines the maximum of a set of values, from scratch.

I'm not sure how to make the function change the new value of Max after a new Max has been found, I'm also not sure if my usage of args is correct.

```
def Maximum(*args):
    Max = 0
    for item in List:
        if item > Max:
            item = Max
    return Max


List = [1,5,8,77,24,95]

maxList = Maximum(List)
print str(maxList)
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: `for item in List` should be `for item in args`.

Comment: Another bug is if `args` is a list of negative numbers, it will return `0`. You could fix it by error handling for when `args` is empty, and then setting `Max = args[0]`

Comment: and key , default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got one line of code backwards. Your if statement is effectively saying that if item is greater than Max, set item to Max. You need to flip that to say if item is greater than Max, set Max to item.

```
if item > Max:
    Max = item
return Max
```

Also, I'm not an expert in Python, but i think you need to change the List inside your function to match the parameter name, in this case args.

Comment: you should return `Max` after the for loop

Answer (score 1):

*args = list of arguments -as positional arguments

You are passing a list as an argument here. So your code should look something like this -

```
def maximum(nums):
   Max = 0
   for item in nums:
       if item > Max:
           Max=item
   return Max

List = [1,5,8,77,24,95]
print maximum(List)
```

This would give you the result : 95.

On the other hand you can use the max built in function to get the maximum number in the list.

```
print max(List)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using reduce():

Python 2

```
def Maximum(data):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x if x > y else y, data)
```

In Python 3, add

```
from functools import reduce
```

Output:

```
print(Maximum([4, 8, 4, 19, -1]))
```

> `19`